# HTML Datalist cannot delete to the page

Tags: html

lately i have a data list tag on my page. I remove it from the page. but when i run the page, data list is there.

```
<input type="text" name="" required="" id="default" autofocus=""
   class="form-control" list="languages" placeholder="Search for Last Name">




  <datalist id="languages">
   <?php
        $sel = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pre_registration WHERE status= 1");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sel)>0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sel)){ ?>
            <option id="<?php echo $row['reg_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo
                                               $row['lname'].' '.$row['fname']; ?>">
    <?php}}
     ?>
  </datalist>
```

this is the script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(function(){
    $('#default').change(function(){
        `document.getElementById("name1").value = $("#languages 
               option[value='" + $('#default').val() + "']").attr('id');
   });
});
```

i already delete this on my page but it is run on my page.

Comment: you question is unclear to me, can you make it live somewhere and give us a real example? However, your script seems wrong but I need to see your HTML part as well before refining for you.

Comment: that codes never been exist on may page. but when i run it. the datalist tag is always there.

Comment: The datalist element provides the ability to offer suggestions for a field such as a search. why you want to remove it ?

Comment: i try the datalist tag because it is new for me. but when i delete the input tag together with datalist tag when i run the page. it is always there. the code is remove but it still run

Comment: I assume, it should be loaded with another script somewhere in your app/web, we need to see a real example maybe a live html page to debug more

Comment: can you paste the full code?